# PHP & MySQL & JS editable table won't update records

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

So I'm trying to use a table to update some records in my database but each time I click on update it won't work and it won't do anything. A part of the code below was found in an another topic but it was incomplete so I added some other things.

**Js script**

```js
$(function(){

    $("#loading").hide();
    var message_status = $("#status");
    $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
        var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
        var value = $(this).text() ;



        $.post('update.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){



            if(data != '')
            {
                message_status.show();
                message_status.text(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},1000);
            }
        });
    });




});
```

This is the table fetching the rows from the database, however everything works besides updating.

**HTML & PHP**

```php
<form method="post" action="update.php">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
                <tr bgcolor="#df4662" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Nickname</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Rank</td>
                </tr>

            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td contenteditable="true" id="id:<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" id="username:<?php echo $row["username"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" id="name:<?php echo $row["steamid"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["steamid"]; ?></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" id="ranks:<?php echo $row["ranks"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["ranks"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
                </table>

</div>
</div>
</form>
```

After a few errors I've been able to have a clean error_logs, but now I don't get any error even after pressing the update button.

**update.php**

```php
<?php  


include '../database.php'


?>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{

    foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)
    {
        $field_id = strip_tags(trim($field_name));

        $split_data = explode(':', $field_id);
        $id = $split_data[1];
        $field_name = $split_data[0];
        if(!empty($id) && !empty($field_name) && !empty($val))
        {

            $affected_rows = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users SET $field_name = '$val' WHERE id = $id");
            echo $affected_rows;

            echo "Updated";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Request";
        }
    }
} 

else {
    echo "Invalid Requests";
}
?>
```

EDIT: Thanking Sam now the problem is just that the record won't update at all

Comment: I may be missing something but it looks like you have a hanging `</a>` in your form's html.

Comment: Ok, edited and thanks. The `</a>` solved the redirect problem but I stil get Invalid Requests when I get redirected on update.php...

Comment: I'll look forward to change to pdo but this page is not yet available for other users but thanks anyway. I'm currently still trying to figure out why the update won't work

Comment: I actually understood the problem.. There was no need of a button to update the row, just losing focus of the cell would update but the mysql won't properly get updated...